# Panda count totals of multiple excel columns

Tags: pandas

I have excel data that i modified to give me
1's = Filled cell
0's = Not Filled cell

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 |

what i want to get is:

|  | Filled | Not Filled |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Column A | 2 | 2 |
| Column B | 1 | 3 |
| Column C | 4 | 0 |
| Column D | 0 | 4 |

i tried:

```
summary_new = df2.groupby(['Column A','Column B','Column C','Column D'], as_index=False).agg(
    FILLED_ITEM = pd.NamedAgg(column=([['Column A','Column B','Column C','Column D']]).astype(int), aggfunc=lambda x: x.eq(1).sum()),
    NOT_FILLED_ITEM = pd.NamedAgg(column=([['Column A','Column B','Column C','Column D']]).astype(int), aggfunc=lambda x: x.eq(0).sum())).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
filled = df.sum()  # or df.ne(0).sum() if you have other values than 0/1
not_filled = len(df) - filled
out = pd.concat([filled, not_filled], keys=['Filled', 'Not Filled'], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
          Filled  Not Filled
Column A       2           2
Column B       1           3
Column C       4           0
Column D       0           4
```

**Edit**:

The one-liner for python > 3.8 with walrus operator:

```
out = pd.concat([filled := df.sum(), len(df) - filled],
                keys=['Filled', 'Not Filled'], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to @Corralien's approach but as a single command, using [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) and [`eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html):

```
out = (df.sum().to_frame(name='Filled')
         .eval('Not_Filled = @df.shape[1]-Filled')
      )
```

Variant: `.eval(...)` can be replaced by `.assign(**{'Not Filled': lambda d: df.shape[1]-d['Filled']})`.

Output:

```
          Filled  Not_Filled
Column A       2           2
Column B       1           3
Column C       4           0
Column D       0           4
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, which uses [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) preceded by [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html#pandas.DataFrame.stack). Then [`unstacks`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) and removes axes names.

```
(df.stack().droplevel(0).reset_index().value_counts()
 .unstack(1, fill_value=0).rename(columns={0:'Not filled', 1:'Filled'})
 .rename_axis(None, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=0))
```

Output:

```
          Not filled  Filled
Column A           2       2
Column B           3       1
Column C           0       4
Column D           4       0
```

Answer (score 1):

With a [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html)ransposed [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
d = {0: "Not Filled", 1: "Filled"}

out = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).rename(d.get).T.fillna(0)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

          Not Filled  Filled
Column A        2.00    2.00
Column B        3.00    1.00
Column C        0.00    4.00
Column D        4.00    0.00

[4 rows x 2 columns]
```